# beanplots: plus sign?

Tags: density-function, outliers, boxplot, kernel-smoothing, statsmodels

I would like to draw **bean plots** using the [statsmodel](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.boxplots.beanplot.html) package for Python. 
In the example provided on the documentation, I see a **red plus sign** in each beanplot:
[image]

What does it represent?

Comment: The median. That is explicit in the document you cite. By default, the median of each set of values is shown as a marker (point symbol) and the mean as a line. (Not your question, but the representation here seems rather busy to me and transposing to horizontal would avoid the clumsy display of labels such as "Strong Democrat".)

Comment: More trivially, spot the typo in the original.